# How to customize Schema.Datetime widget for just displaying year,month,day format in Dexterity enviroment?

Tags: plone, datetime-format, dexterity

I will like to customize Schema.Datetime field widget for local time format just displaying year-month-date.
Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use the **Date** field for this and it will automatically render a date-only widget:

```py
from my.package import _
from plone.supermodel import model
from zope import schema

class IMyContentType(model.Schema):
    ...

    start_date = schema.Date(
        title=_(u'Start date'),
        description=_(u'This widget will show only the date.'),
        required=False,
    )
```